# error in vscode suggesting "surround with..." in TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm testing my first lines of code in TypeScript testing if it was configured and working

I tested

```
let user = {name:"matt", age: 33};
console.log(user.name);
console.log(user.email);
```

I get a red line under email, but instead of having a popup i get the snippet to surround `email` with different snippets, rather than showing error for unassigned variable

[image]

same goes for other errors like type conflicts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Missing "problem popup" turned out to be an error in my config file .json

changed `"editor.hover.enabled":true,`